# Terraform Heroku provider: Does it have resource for dyno?

Tags: heroku, terraform

Using terraform, I could create Heroku applications, create and attach add-ons and put the applications in a pipeline. After the infrastructure is created, everything is good except the dynos are not started. I used `heroku/nodejs` buildpack. Terraform's [Heroku provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/heroku/) does not provide any explicit resource type that corresponds to [Heroku dyno](https://www.heroku.com/dynos). Are we supposed to manually push application for deployment on Heroku when the necessary add-ons and pipeline are created with Terraform?

I googled a lot but couldn't figure out what could be the reason for the dynos not getting started after necessary infrastructure is in place.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

so today I wanted to test heroku with terraform and got the same issue
it looks like you need to push your app to the `git_url` reference provided by `heroku_app` 
made a working example at https://github.com/nroitero/terraform_heroku

Comment: would be nice if you could add helpful documentation to README file of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing as the example below, and it works.

First, defining the heroku app:

```
resource "heroku_app" "this" {
    name   = var.HEROKU_APP_NAME
    region = var.HEROKU_REGION
    space = var.HEROKU_SPACE
    internal_routing = var.HEROKU_INTERNAL_ROUTING
```

Then, indicating where the node application is:

```
resource "heroku_build" "this" {
  app = heroku_app.this.name
  #buildpacks = [var.BUILDPACK_URL]

  source = {
    #url = var.SOURCE_URL
    #version = var.SOURCE_VERSION
    #testing path instead of source
    path =  var.SOURCE_PATH
  }
}
```

And to define dynos, I'm using:

```
resource "heroku_formation" "this" {
  app        = heroku_app.this.name
  type       = var.HEROKU_FORMATION_TYPE
  quantity   = var.HEROKU_FORMATION_QTY
  size       = var.HEROKU_FORMATION_SIZE
  depends_on = [heroku_build.this]
}
```

For the dyno size parameter (var.HEROKU_FORMATION_SIZE), use the official dyno type "name" as listed on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types.

For private spaces, names are: private-s, private-m and private-l.